# more simple way to get the name and value attribution in MozillaCookieJar object

Tags: python-3.x, cookies

```
type(x)
<class 'http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar'>
print(x)
<MozillaCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='csrftoken', value='dhXkO4rh0MbahP1iafYZ1ONWqdFXYureizoCMjlIQ4Ths8QCPAuAWONR0FbILvUI', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='www.alphavantage.co', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1541556759, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

To get the name and value in x.

```
for item in x:
    print(item.name,item.value)
```

`x.name` and `x.value` can't get right output,is there more simple way to get the name and value attribution in MozillaCookieJar object?

Comment: I tried this out and it worked just fine for me... What seems to be the problem?

Comment: To make it more shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're misunderstanding what `MozillaCookieJar` is. You have a `MozillaCookieJar` object like so:

```
<MozillaCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='csrftoken', value='dhXkO4rh0MbahP1iafYZ1ONWqdFXYureizoCMjlIQ4Ths8QCPAuAWONR0FbILvUI', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='www.alphavantage.co', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1541556759, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

which is an object that "holds" the `Cookie` objects within. Your `MozillaCookieJar` has a single `Cookie` object in it. If you could get that `Cookie` object by itself, you could access its member variables using `Cookie.name` and `Cookie.value`. The only problem is to get that Cookie object by itself you need the `MozillaCookieJar` object to have an `__getitem__` method, the method used to get an item from a `list` using indices like `some_list[0]` or slices `some_list[:10]`. Sadly the `MozillaCookieJar` object does not have that but it does have the `__iter__` method allowing you to iterate through *all* the `Cookie` objects (like you did with the `for` loop). Therefore, your method is the shortest and cleanest method possible:

```
for cookie in cookie_jar:
    print(cookie.name,cookie.value)
```

To select specific cookies, let's say `csrftoken`s:

```
csrftoken_cookies = [cookie for cookie in cookie_jar if cookie.name == 'csrf_token']
```

And if you're sure there is only one:

```
csrftoken_cookie = [cookie for cookie in cookie_jar if cookie.name == 'csrf_token'][0]
```